Clicking on the visualforce link used in LWC component from mobile device, the related visualforce controller class is executing twice
I am embedding a visualforce url with an image in LWC component through app builder page. I have defined the image property in the xml file.
<template lwc:if={mobileView}>
    <div class="image-grid bannerMobile">
        <template for:each={imageList} for:item="image">
            <div key={image.id} class="image-item">
                <a href={image.href}>
                <img src={image.url} alt={image.name} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

In XML file I configured the property like below
<property name="img1name" type="String" default="test.png" label="Image 1 Filename" description=" Test e.g. Photo.jpg"  />
            <property name="img1AltText" type="String" default="test" label="Image 1 Alt Text" description="Test description image 1"  />
            <property name="img1Description" type="String" default="The description" label="Description" description="The description of the image."  />
            <property name="img1header" type="String" default="The header" label="Header" description="The header for the image."  />
            <property name="img1href" type="String" default="https://www.example.com" label="href" description="The href link."  />

My Visualforce page is simple -
<apex:page controller="UrlRedirectController" action="{!redirect}"></apex:page>

In the apex class we are using Apexpages.currentPage().getUrl() to fetch the url and calculating the number of clicks on the visualforce url done by user.
This apex class is executing multiple times while user click on the link (One time) from mobile ONLY( Salesforce1 mobile app). For Desktop the class is executing only one time and working fine. Can someone please help me to prevent the multiple time execution of the visualforce controller class?

What have you tried? What part isn't working?  At a high level, couldn't you disable prevent the behaviour of the link once it's been clicked?

The visualforce controller class "UrlRedirectController" is being executed multiple times once user clicks on the visualforce link/url that is being used in LWC component. This is the issue. Without LWC it is working correctly.
